# In a LazyVerticalGrid, can we determine the number of columns to span dynamically?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose's `LazyVerticalGrid` when can specify a number of columns to span in the `item` or `items` functions like in this example:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun LazyVerticalGridSpan(orders: List<String>) {
        val sections = (0 until 250).toList().chunked(5)
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(50.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            sections.forEachIndexed { index, items ->
                item(span = { GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan) }) {
                    Text(
                        "This is section $index",
                        Modifier
                            .border(border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Cyan))
                            .height(80.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    )
                }
                items(
                    items,
                    // not required as it is the default
                    span = { GridItemSpan(1) }) {
                    Text(
                        "Item $it", 
                        Modifier
                            .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
                            .height(80.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used Accompanist's [`FlowColumn`](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/) as my items, and set these FlowColumn composables up to line up with the width of 1 to N columns in `LazyVerticalGrid`. What I need to be able to do is measure the width of individual composables before providing a span value for each item. I am simplifying the requirements a bit, but that's the major challenge.

I've tried using SubcomposeLayout for each individual view in the grid, but then I won't get a width until after having to provide a span.

example using the previous code:

```kotlin
                items(
                    items,
                    // not required as it is the default
                    span = { GridItemSpan(1) }) {
                    SubcomposeLayout() {
                       val placeable = subcompose(
                           ...
                       ).first().measure()
                       layout(...) {...}
                    }
                }
```

I'm aware that you can provide conditional logic in the `span` lambda, but I haven't seen a way to make actual measurements before providing a span.